# event callback argument is empty

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I've got event listeners defined as `<AgGridReact>` properties and then also just added this to my `onGridReady` callback:

```
grid.api.addEventListener('sortChanged',
    evt => {
      console.log(evt);
      debugger;
    });
```

Either way, the `evt` object is empty (an empty object, not undefined). Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong? The documentation (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/) doesn't say anything about what to expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is fine, but all 3 of the "sort" events:

```
sortChanged
beforeSortChanged
afterSortChanged
```

are notification only events - no event object are passed into the event itself